# Making PDO statements work

Tags: php, security, pdo

I was using standard mysql_real_escape_string(); and was told it was secure but was told also that PDO makes better security so using this kind of script below:

Code:

```
 <?php
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName',
          'username', 'password',
          array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

  $query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE title = :title';

  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindValue(':title', $myTitle);
  $stmt->execute();

  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  // ...
  }
  ?>
```

My Questions:

Do i have to use the $db instead of just using include("config.php"); and can i use the config file in the standard format?

How to i echo the rows using the query above? Do i just simply to $something = $row['title']; within the while { }?

And, Am i doing this right?

Comment: you know, nothing is secure by itself. only knowledge will make your code secure, not the function you are using.

Comment: lol now you are confusing me.  I told the samething to the people who told me PDO was more secure.  But they made a statement that there are other things that mysql_real_escape_string(); can't capture and that PDO does it automatically...

Comment: automatically? you have just changed `mysql_real_escape_string();` to `$stmt->bindValue`. that's all.

Comment: put PDO is a little more secure when used mindlessly, I have to admit. your query won't work if you forget to bind but it will run if you forget to escape.

Comment: so in other words mysql_real_escape_string(); is better as well?  I am new so please enlighten me.

Comment: who says it's better? I'm just says thet knowledge, not function will make you secure.

Comment: ok so what are the things i should be looking out for?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use PDO or any other API using placeholders in your SQL (like `:title`) will stop short any number of SQL injection attacks.

And yes $row{'columnname'] or $row[1] will retrieve the values for each column.

Comment: any number? what if i have to sort my table based on user input?

Comment: What it protects against is SQL injection. Think about what woul happen if a bad guy enters this in the name field :->xxxxx'; delete from customers;<--